# What does a P-Channel MOSFET symbol with body connected to source mean?

Tags: mosfet, symbol

I was just trying to [source a power MOSFET](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/b6/cc/21/ab/37/07/4d/f0/DM00080348.pdf/files/DM00080348.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00080348.pdf), and I stumbled across a very odd symbol for a P-channel MOSFET.

[image: Image from the datasheet.]

I know that the arrow pointing out means it is P-channel, and I know that the dashed bar means it is enhancement mode. However, I have never seen a P-channel MOSFET that has the body terminal connected to source, every other symbol for them I have seen has body connected to drain.

My question is whether this difference in the symbol signifies that the component behaves differently than a standard P-channel MOSFET?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Oh! Silly me, the body is connected to source on the symbols I usually see! It's just that P-channel MOSFETs are usually drawn with source pointing up, with N-channel having source pointing down!

Serves me right for making assumptions I guess.

Comment: That is correct. This is actually a very _standard_ circuit symbol for FET devices. However, this FET device right here is _neglecting the Body Effect_ so the bulk/body/substrate (whatever you want to call it) is tied to the source. It is very odd that the pMOS symbol has the arrow pointing outwards because you would think if the arrow is pointing outwards, it would be an nMOS device, but it's not... I don't know why it does this other than to indicate that the current is _sourcing/leaving_ the source.